# Deploying WCF Services

Tags: wcf, web-services, deployment

I have a WCF visual studio project, which contains many SVC files.
Can I compile each SVC file into its own dll file?
my target is to be able to deploy each svc file separately without touching other services, but maybe keep them on the same website
what options I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot compile the svc files.

You can however compile your actual service code into an assembly (if you haven't stuck it into `YourFile.svc.cs`  codebehind file), and then deploy that compiled assembly into the `bin` directory below the virtual directory where you svc files exist.

If you want to have an assembly for each service, you will need to create a class library project for each service, put the service implementation inside that, compile it, and then deploy that resulting assembly into the bin directory.

The svc files must be deployed as is, and they must be copied into a virtual directory (or a subdirectory thereof) in IIS.